# Save something in settingsfile or.. ? in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, save, application-settings

I am implementing an application and I have a few lists with some stuff in it, which is always the same, but I don't want to implement this in my real logic stuff.

Is there any way to save these items in your application? I've read some things about saving these items in a settingsfile.

Is this the best way, or there are better ways? and how can I do this?

Comment: 1. save to Database 2. save to settingfile 3. use "class" to implement it. If it is always be the same, I recommend 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save in XML. You can bind directly to xml in wpf. See: http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/04/binding-to-xml/

Answer (score 1):

You can save it in the [application settings file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the content of the list is supposed to never be changed you can make them private static fields in a static class the provides a mthod to create a new instance of the list.

If the content of the list is supposed to be changed, it is a good idea to store it in the application settings file.

If the content of the list is supposed to be changed per user you should save it in the user settings file.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the content itself, I like to load the content of list into a database table. For example, a list of school would be stored in a table calle T_Ref_Schools. The Ref indicated to me that those values can be changed over time but not often.